# Great books in Experimental Organic Chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, books

This summer I've quite a lot of free time, so I decided to study experimental Organic synthesis. I don't even have basic experimental chemistry knowledge, however my theory is pretty firm( Clayden level maybe ). What I need is good experimental organic chemistry books. Books with good illustrations will be welcome.

Comment: Search for books on Practical Organic Chemistry

Comment: Shopping question are frowned upon here. Online bookshops are full of books on organic synthesis.